# Код циклической перестановки

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Возникла сложность с кодом циклической перестановки на С. Полное условие задачи:

> Написать программу, которая позволит ввести два числа n и k типа unsigned с клавиатуры, напечатать их на дисплее, и используя битовые операции сделать в числе n циклическую перестановку на k бит вправо.

С первой частью задачи проблем не возникло. Заранее спасибо. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned m;
......
// k = k % (sizeof(n)*8);
m = n << (sizeof(n)*8 - k);
n = n >> k;
n = n | m;
```

Comment: 1. обезопасить себя от выходов за границу, можно и не делать, тогда в таких случаях всегда будет ноль
2. Запоминаем затираемую при сдвиге часть, заодно сдвинув ее в начало
3. Сдвигаем
4. Добавляем затертую часть.

Comment: слегка ошибся в спешке, уже поправил, должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

всего битов: sizeof(n)*8

Маска первых k битов: maskA

Маска вторых n-k битов: maskB

```
for(i=0;i<k;i++) maskA|=1<<i;
for(i=k;i<n;i++) maskB|=1<<i;
a=n&maskA;
b=n&maskB;
new_n=(b>>k)+(a<<k);
```

если не ошибаюсь то так... не запускал. но принцы тот-же.